# error in database connection in php with firebase

Tags: php, database, firebase, web

I have got a php script for connect php to firebase realtime database.I can run the script successfully from the command line, but when I try it from a web browser(on my host), it doesn't work. `

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount =  ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/blocktask-b86a0-firebase-adminsdk-h6093-19e2b6f222.json')
$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://blocktask-b86a0.firebaseio.com')
    ->create();
    
$databasse = $firebase -> getDatabase();

?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgbsQ.png)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$firebase' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\xamp\htdocs\firebase\includes\dbconfig.php on line 9

Comment: Kindly edit your Question to include the error as text in a code block. Do not provide clarifications in comments. Also, do not post images of code or errors. It would also be helpful if you would identify what code line that is "line 9".

Comment: Previous error is now removed but here is another error which I am posting i in comment

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private method Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile() from context '' in D:\xamp\htdocs\firebase\dbconfig.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xamp\htdocs\firebase\dbconfig.php on line 8

Comment: if you could help me with this please

Comment: You'll need to use the "edit" option as highlighted in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtHQC.png) I can't help to answer your Question as this is not my areas of expertise. I can only help to tell you how to write your Question. This may also help you: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been following a tutorial that's targeted at version 4.x of [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php), but are using a 5.x release in your project, in which some methods have been removed or have been made non-public.

There are two approaches you could follow:

1. Stick with a 4.x release to be able to continue following the tutorial. To achieve this, change the requirement for `kreait/firebase-php` in your `composer.json` from `5.x` to `4.x`

   To do so, ensure your `composer.json` to have the line

   `"kreait/firebase-php": "^4.44"`

   Going forward, you should use the documentation of release 4.x at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/4.44.0/
2. Adapt your code to the changed method signature of release 5.x. For this, when you encounter issues like the one you described your original post, check the SDK  usage docs on https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and adapt your code accordingly.

---

In your specific case, the solution is to change your code to

```php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/blocktask-b86a0-firebase-adminsdk-h6093-19e2b6f222.json');
    
$database = $factory->createDatabase();
```

This is also described in the [SDK Docs' Troubleshooting page](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html).

Please note that, in most cases, you don't need to specify the database URI explicitly - this is only necessary if the database URI is not based on the project ID of your project.